# Chrome low fps - devtools long update layer tree and composite layers with very few layers on page

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I am attempting to debug low FPS on my page. I see a lot of time spent per frame on "Update Layer Tree" and "Composite Layers". Update layer tree is consistently between 10-20ms and composite layers is between 6-10ms.

My confusion comes from the fact that there are only 4 layers on my page including the root layer. How can update layer tree and compositing take so much time when there are only 4 layers?

Along with this there are long blank spaces in my frames. Also chrome identifies my scroll area as a slow scroll rect, but simply says "undefined" about the layer.

I must be missing some information in the devtools that can help me understand the low FPS. This screenshot captures the odd behavior.

[image: devtools screenshot]

Edit: I applied transform: translateZ(0) to my scroll container. This forces some more layers to be created. It seems to have sped things up significantly but I still have some very slow frames where devtools gives me no info. Just long blank stretches. See this screenshot:

[image: devtools screenshot 2]

Comment: The amount of layers alone is not the deciding factor. The amount of DOM elements in each affected layer is important too. The blank space probably means the browser didn't make it in time to display this particular frame and dropped it.

Comment: Check your total DOM node count, as wOxxOm mentioned. That's a common cause of long Update Layer Tree events. The Audits panel has an audit that tells you if your page has an excessive number of DOM nodes.

Comment: @KayceBasques any idea how many nodes would be considered too much in each layer? I have a list of 44 items each in their own layer, and 8-13 child elements within each item. The total DOM count is 676 nodes, which is lower than the 1500 threshold given in some online guides I've seen. But I still have this problem.